# Cannot auto reconnect Magic Trackpad 2 since Kernel 5.0

Tags: kernel, bluetooth, 19.04, magic-trackpad

> Ubuntu 18.x | 19.04 on kernel < 5.0 works as expected.

Prior to kernel 5.0 I was using 4.8 and the Magic Trackpad was able to automatically reconnect (via a simple click on the pad) after a system reboot/ sleep/ timeout bluetooth disconnect.

Now, whenever the system disconnects from the trackpad, I have to manually reconnect either via UI or bluetoothctl.

The trackpad is set as Trusted, and the hassle is that I have to first close the trackpad via its only button, wait for it to not search for the last paired device (I think that's what it does ~around 20-30 sec), and sometimes I even have to `sudo service bluetooth restart` before reconnecting.

I've also tried with a magic keyboard (gen1) and the behaviour is identical.

I'm on:

```
Ubuntu 19.04
Kernel 5.3
Bluez 5.50
Lenovo Legion Y530
```

Any Ideas why this happens?